# How to get data from AngularJS callback function in loopback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I want to know how the retrieve "good" array from angular function. I have this function in angular:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,Communications,$http,$filter) {

$rootScope.getCommunication = 
function(object_type,val,id,isType,isSendSms,getNotes){

  var array = {};
  var newArr = [];

  // getting data from mysql data 
  var myVals = Communications.find({
        filter: {
          where: {
            and : [{
              communications_type_code : val
            },{
              object_id : id
            },{
              object_type : object_type
            }]
          }
        } 
      }).$promise
        .then(function(data) {

          for(var ind=0; ind<data.length; ind++){
            array['address_type'] = data[ind].address_type;
            array['contact_value'] = data[ind].contact_value;
            array['send_sms'] = data[ind].send_sms;
          }

          newArr.push(array);
           return newArr;
        });
  return newArr;
};
});
```

When I call to the function in Angular controller like this:

```
var arr = $rootScope.getCommunication(2,3,$id);
console.log(arr);
```

I am getting in the console something like this:

[image]

When I call to arr[0] I get undefined.
How can i recieve this data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise, currently you are returning the array before it is updated.  Async works by running all the synchronous code first then running anything async.

```
var arr = []; // runs first
promise.then(function(result){arr = result}) // runs third.
return arr; // runs second
```

You need to change your code to return the promise.  However this also means your calling code has to handle async code.

```
function asyncFunc() {
 return promise.then(function(result){return result});
}

asyncFunc().then(function(result) {console.log(result)}) // output is the value of result.
```

In the context of the code you gave above

```
app.run(function($rootScope,Communications,$http,$filter) {

$rootScope.getCommunication = 
function(object_type,val,id,isType,isSendSms,getNotes){
  // getting data from mysql data 
  return Communications.find({
        filter: {
          where: {
            and : [{
              communications_type_code : val
            },{
              object_id : id
            },{
              object_type : object_type
            }]
          }
        } 
      }).$promise
        .then(function(data) {
          var array = {};
          var newArray = [];
          for(var ind=0; ind<data.length; ind++){
            array['address_type'] = data[ind].address_type;
            array['contact_value'] = data[ind].contact_value;
            array['send_sms'] = data[ind].send_sms;
          }

          newArr.push(array);
           return newArr;
        });
};
});
```

and the calling function:

```
var arr = $rootScope.getCommunication(2,3,$id)
                    .then(function(arr){console.log(arr)})
```

Comment: I amg getting `angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` from the call of the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback in following way

```
app.run(function($rootScope,Communications,$http,$filter) {

$rootScope.getCommunication = 
function(object_type,val,id,isType,isSendSms,getNotes, callback){

  var array = {};
  var newArr = [];

  // getting data from mysql data 
  var myVals = Communications.find({
        filter: {
          where: {
            and : [{
              communications_type_code : val
            },{
              object_id : id
            },{
              object_type : object_type
            }]
          }
        } 
      }).$promise
        .then(function(data) {

          for(var ind=0; ind<data.length; ind++){
            array['address_type'] = data[ind].address_type;
            array['contact_value'] = data[ind].contact_value;
            array['send_sms'] = data[ind].send_sms;
          }

          newArr.push(array);

           //return using callback
           return callback(newArr);

        });

  //return using callback
  return callback(newArr);

};
});
```

And use callback to access result

```
$rootScope.getCommunication(2,3,$id, function(result){
  var arr = result
})
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined callback`

Comment: make identical/equal parameter when calling function getCommunication

Comment: I still get an error `TypeError: callback is not a function`

Comment: check my updated answer and fit the function where you need , the way of callback function is correct.